# How To Save State Of RecyclerView Checkbox On Screen Rotation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox, screen-rotation, linkedhashset

On screenrotation the selected items get unselected, I want to save its state.
I have all these forms in recyclerView which get selected on click. This is the code in onListItemClick

```
 private void onListItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Cursor cursor = instanceAdapter.getCursor();
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);

        CheckBox checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());

        long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(InstanceProviderAPI.InstanceColumns._ID));

        if (selectedInstances.contains(id)) {
            selectedInstances.remove(id);
        } else {
            selectedInstances.add(id);
        }
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        sendButton.setEnabled(selectedInstances.size() > 0);

        toggleButtonLabel();
    }
```

where selectedInstances is a LinkedHashSet

```
private LinkedHashSet<Long> selectedInstances;
```

Here is the GIF

[image: Here's the GIF]

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can store it in a database or anything that's 'persistent', then you could just keep a list/array of booleans with as many entries as your ListView. When you check the second checkbox, set array[1] = true.

Then in your adapter you just check the state of the position of the list for the current item.

Somewhat of an example

```
boolean[] checkedState = new boolean[list.count];

private void onListItemClick(View view, int position) {
    //...
    checkedState[position] = //checked state
}

//adapter

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //...

    checkBox.isChecked = checkedState[position]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) Stores UI-related data that isn't destroyed on app rotations.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to keep UI states you can use the methods onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState of activity object for save that data in the Bundle type parameter as follow bellow:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
     String setting; 
     state.putString("KeyName", setting);
}
```

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
     super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
     String setting; 
     setting = state.getString("KeyName");
}
```

The most correct way according to Android Developer Documentation's to persist that data, so when the app's finished and then it's started again the app will can retrieve that data from local storage.

It can be by *SharedPreferences* or *Room database* depending on data complexity. Like the data are settings, so I believe you'll want to store one when you had finished your app and to retrieve one when you start you app again.

References:

1. [Saving UI States](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states)
2. [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)
3. [Save key-value data](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)
4. [Save data in a local database using Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/)
5. [RoomDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase)
6. [Android Jetpack: Room](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKWh4ckvFPM)
7. [What’s New in Room (Android Dev Summit '19)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aJsh6P00c0)